# Edit gridview row asp.net without using commandfield

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I would like to make a column editable in a gridview but without the edit column (the one with the keys update, cancel ...) due to space problems. I tried to recall the javascript functions related to those buttons in the onRowDataBound  but onclick event is not taken. Here my code. Can anyone help me please?

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowIndex == GridView1.EditIndex)    //GridView is in edit mode
            {
                //update or cancel buttons
                LinkButton updateBtn = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0];             
                string updateScript = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(updateBtn, ""); 
                Button1.Attributes["onclick"] = updateScript;                                  

                string cancelScript = string.Format("javascript:__doPostBack('{0}','Cancel${1}')", GridView1.ID, e.Row.RowIndex);
                Button2.Attributes["onclick"] = cancelScript;
            }
            else   //GridView is in read mode
            {
                //edit button
                string editScript = string.Format("javascript:__doPostBack('{0}','Edit${1}')", GridView1.ID, e.Row.RowIndex);
                e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = editScript;     
            }

        }
        if (GridView1.EditIndex >= 0)
        {
            Button1.Enabled = true;
            Button2.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Button1.Enabled = false;
            Button2.Enabled = false;
        }

    }

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="PKCOD" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="10"
                                                CssClass="auto-style1" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <%--
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="QUANTITA" SortExpression="QUANTITA">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("QUANTITA") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    <br />
                    <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" EnableClientScript="False" ErrorMessage="ErrorMessage" MaximumValue="999" MinimumValue="0" Type="Integer">Valori tra 0 e 999</asp:RangeValidator>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("QUANTITA") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
             --%>

            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="QUANTITA" SortExpression="QUANTITA">
                <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="textBoxQuantita" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("QUANTITA") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" Type="Double" MinimumValue="0" MaximumValue="999" ControlToValidate="textBoxQuantita" runat="server"
                        ErrorMessage="Inserisci solo numeri compresi tra 0 e 999"></asp:RangeValidator>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>



            <asp:BoundField DataField="CODICE" HeaderText="CODICE" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CODICE" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DESCRIZIONE" HeaderText="DESCRIZIONE" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="DESCRIZIONE" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CATEGORIA" HeaderText="CATEGORIA" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CATEGORIA" Visible="False" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PKCOD" HeaderText="PKCOD" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="PKCOD" InsertVisible="False" Visible="False" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="USERNAME" HeaderText="USERNAME" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="USERNAME" Visible="False" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="USERID" HeaderText="USERID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="USERID" Visible="False" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="USERDT" HeaderText="USERDT" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="USERDT" Visible="False" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="STATO" HeaderText="STATO" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="STATO" Visible="False" />      
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: You can get creative with the item and edit templates. Have you tried creating a layout that fits in the space you have?

Comment: I haven't tried with the layout because I would like to delete that column. 
I'm working on a web app that must also work on mobile. I need space for the gridview.

Comment: The layout need not be a single row of columns. Look at other examples of editable lists on other sites.